# Solr search on functional query output

Tags: solr

I have a expression `if(and(tf(MSTATUS_FILTER,Y),if(tf(PARTNER_MSTATUS,$loggedInProfileObj->getMSTATUS()),0,1)),1,0)`
the output of this expression is either `1` or `0`.

I need to perform a search on solr based on the output of this expression.
Here `$loggedInProfileObj->getMSTATUS()` gives a value at run time of sending a query on solr

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if any better way to perform this.
But, you can check for the Filter query support of function queries with [FunctionRangeQParserPlugin](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_3_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/search/FunctionRangeQParserPlugin.html)

e.g. Filter query example: `fq={!frange l=0 u=0.99}if(and(tf(MSTATUS_FILTER,Y),if(tf(PARTNER_MSTATUS,$loggedInProfileObj->getMSTATUS()),0,1)),1,0)`